# custom tag for each post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Currently I have two custom post type say article#1 and article#2 . I want to create custom tag also for each post type . I mean if I create a tag for article#1 it will not show under article#2 post type .

Please help me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add additional entry in $args argument called 'taxonomies' in your register_post_type something like

```
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
                'taxonomies' => array('tag')
      );
```

hope this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

There is tag option in the post back end you need to add the  tag there   after that  you have to call these tag on front end    you can use the  function for this

```
  <?php $posttags = get_the_tags();
                    if ($posttags) {
                       echo get_the_tag_list('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
                    }

     ?>
```